# Stage plans - input lists, output lists, monitor lists

Tags: stage-setup

I am going to make a stage plot for my school project.

I have researched how and I have found lots of examples. The thing that is unclear are the following

Input list
Output list
Monitor list
FoH inserts

It feels like a Monitor List maybe a subset of Output list but it may be an overloaded term?

I also have seen examples ([example1](https://blog.discmakers.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Input-List-Social.jpg) and [example2](https://www.hatefx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/HATEFX_INPUT-LIST.jpg)) of monitor information (or [FoH inserts](https://totalproaudio.stevebunting.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Channel-List.png)) in the input list which has confused me even more.

My question is, what are the differences between input list, output list, monitor list and FoH inserts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input is as it says - mostly mics, for drums, for picking up guitar amp sounds, vox, etc.

Output is also as it says, what comes out of the mixer, in whatever mixed state.

Monitor list is whatever gets fed back through the monitor (foldback) system. There may be several different mixes here. Vocalists may want their own voice, plus guitar or keys, drums will want themselves (!) plus maybe bass, and a little bit of vox. Guitar may want nothing, as their amp would be behind them, making it its own monitor.

FoH inserts are the front of house (main p.a.) effects. Vox would prefer a little reverb, drums dry, and so on, it's personal choice here.

On a big rig, there will be the facility to provide all this, with several mixes for monitor, going through several different foldback speakers, or better still, I.E. monitors, which totally eliminate feedback. Effects may be on a separate rack, and again, get fed both to FoH and monitors if wanted.

Lots of knobs, lots of control - if one knows what one is doing. A good sound guy will listen not only to the sound (!) but to the requirements of individuals, then attempt to get FoH and monitor mixes appropriate for the band, but also for the room. Not an easy task. I've found that the best sound guys are musos, who can understand what musos want, and are talking about.

Comment: Thanks - is it common for the mixes of the monitor to be defined in the stage plot itself, or would you think it's common to simply have a chat with the sound engineer?

Comment: From past experience (as the sound guy) the more discerning performers want to have the same sound in the monitors as they produce FoH. But that may not always be the case. And some sound guys seem to have their own end product in mind, which I've found from being at the other end of the train. Not always good!